# how to column span in pdf Table.fromTextArray() function in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

How do I create a table using flutter pdf like this
[image: This is my sample table]

please help me

I am using `Table.fromTextArray()` function but I can't cut one column or row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make table with [markdown](https://pub.dev/packages/markdown) package

```
Markdown(
  data: '<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>'
)
```

I think using MD is the easier method

Comment: sorry, Iam started with pdf so i can't change now, i will try this in next project, but is there any way to span column in pdf